# Show/Hide text box for email input based on AD user result

Tags: vb.net

I'm still a bit of a VB Noob and I am having some trouble getting this to work correctly. The code looks like it should work, but I am obviously missing something...

What I'm trying to do is to get the users email address from `DirectoryServices` when the form loads & If there is no AD user email available, show (unhide) a text box to allow the user to enter their email address. What I have will pull the users email from AD, but will not show the textbox if Directy services is not available. I have tried moving `UserEmailAdd.Visible = False` and `lblEmail.Visible = False` to the Form Load and the setting the value to True, but I'm not having much luck

Here is what I have so far:

```
    Private Sub FormTicket_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.CenterToScreen()
    BtnSCR.Hide()
    LblScreenshot.Hide()

    'Get current users email address from AD or input
    Dim currentADUser As System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal
    currentADUser = System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current
    Dim userEmail = currentADUser.EmailAddress

    If currentADUser IsNot Nothing Then
        ' user exists
        LblEmail.Visible = False
        UserEmailAdd.Visible = False
        txtSummary.Focus()
        MailUser = userEmail
        'Catch ex As Exception
    Else
        ' user does *not* exist
        UserEmailAdd.Visible = True
        LblEmail.Visible = True
        UserEmailAdd.Focus()
        MailUser = UserEmailAdd.Text
        'End Try
    End If
```

Comment: When you can't see an issue just by looking at code, obviously just looking at it is not enough. That's why you need to debug your code. That means setting a breakpoint, stepping through the code line by line and testing the state at each step. If you do that, even if you still don't know how to solve the problem, you can tell us EXACTLY where and how the behaviour of the code differs form your expectations. I can see one obvious issue just by looking though. How does it make sense to get an email address from something before you check whether that something exists?

Comment: I figured the IF block was doing that check. I must have missed something there... As for the debug, I'll step through and post an update with what I find. Thank you for the info.

Comment: The `If` statement is testing whether `currentADUser` is `Nothing` or not but what point is there to that if you have already tried to get `currentADUser.EmailAddress`? That will throw a `NullReferenceException` if `currentADUser` is `Nothing` so you'll never get to the `If` statement. This is what happens when you write code without knowing what it has to do. I mean steps to get to a result, not just the result itself. If you had written an algorithm you would never have said *"use X then check whether X exists"*, which is why you do write an algorithm first.

Answer (score 0):

So after some testing (trial & error), I was able to make this work. This may not be the best way, but it suits my purpose for now and I will continue to work on cleaning it up.

I determined if there was a local domain and if the user had an account & email address. If so, I populated the `UserEmailAdd` textbox with this value and made the label and field hidden. If no local domain/user was found, the label and textbox were then unhidden and the user was now able to enter their email address which in both cases provided the users `mail.From` address.

Here is what I did:

```
    Try
        ' check if domain user exists
        Dim currentADUser As System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal
        currentADUser = System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current
        Dim userEmail = currentADUser.EmailAddress
        If currentADUser.EmailAddress IsNot Nothing Then
            LblEmail.Hide() 
            UserEmailAdd.Hide() 
            UserEmailAdd.Text = userEmail
            txtSummary.Focus()
        End If
    ' local domain user does not exist
    Catch ex As Exception
        UserEmailAdd.Show() 
        LblEmail.Show() 
        UserEmailAdd.Focus()
    End Try
 ...

    mail.From = New MailAddress(UserEmailAdd.Text)
```

jmcilhinney, thank you for prompting some more thought on my part. I'm obviously not any sort of programmer and I have A LOT to learn yet. But your comments helped me to take another look at this and figure out a different way.